# System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified error

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

I have a System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified error, you can see the output of the console [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCiFW.png) .

Here is my code, I removed many lines, so that the structure would be easier to read.

```
static public void searchCode2(Dictionary<string, string> MList)
    {

        using (SqlConnection connection3 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString))
        {


            connection3.Open();
            SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(null, connection3);

            var keysWithMatchingValues = MList.Where(p => Equals(p.Value, "0")).Select(p => p.Key);

            // ce for devrait macher, meme s'il y plusieurs requetes
            // Tthe fallowing line is where the error point out.
            foreach (var key in keysWithMatchingValues)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(" missing list");
                string[] motToCut = key.ToString().Split(' ');
                Dictionary<string, int> MoviesListMissing = new Dictionary<string, int>();
                Dictionary<string, string> MoviesListMissingCode = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                Dictionary<string, DateTime> MoviesListMissingDate = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();


                //// on va chercher si un des elements du dico n'a pas été récupéré.
                command2.CommandText = "";
                int counter = 0;

                foreach (string word_cutted in motToCut)
                {
                    // on considere que les mots qui ont plus d'une lettre
                    if (word_cutted.Length > 1)
                    {

                        command2.CommandText += "select Code, Titre, Date from Data where Titre LIKE '%" + word_cutted + "%';";
                        counter++;
                        Console.WriteLine("word_cutted : {0} ", word_cutted);
                    }
                }

                command2.Prepare();  // Calling Prepare after having set the Commandtext and parameters.

                SqlDataReader reader2 = command2.ExecuteReader();


                try
                {



                    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                    {
                        //CODES
                    }
                    bool MoviesListMissingisEmpty = (MoviesListMissing.Count == 0);
                    if (!MoviesListMissingisEmpty)
                    {


                        //CODES
                    }

                    // liste le dictionnaire
                    foreach (string key2 in MList.Keys)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Last version : {0}, {1} ", key2, MList[key2]);
                    }


                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
                    Console.WriteLine("Last version : {0}", e);
                }
                finally
                {
                    // Always call Close when done reading.
                    reader2.Close();

                }

            }

            connection3.Close();
            // THIS WON'T PRINT
            Console.WriteLine(" Avant var key in keysWithMatchingValues ");



        }


    }
```

For some reason what I put after

```
 connection3.Close();
```

won't work, and I can't figure out the reason. In some similar topics, it is said to use the lock function, but i don't where. ( I tried some places but it did not work).

Here is the complete code if it may help:

```
   static public void searchCode2(Dictionary<string, string> MList)
    {

        using (SqlConnection connection3 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DistriDBEntities2"].ConnectionString))
        {


            connection3.Open();
            SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(null, connection3);

            DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
            bool pbBool = false;
            string motFinal = "";
            var keysWithMatchingValues = MList.Where(p => Equals(p.Value, "0")).Select(p => p.Key);
            //Where(p => p.Value == "a").Select(p => p.Key);

            // ce for devrait macher, meme s'il y plusieurs requetes

            foreach (var key in keysWithMatchingValues)
            {

                pbBool = true;
                Console.WriteLine(" missing list");
                //literaltest.Text += "<br/>" + motFinal + ", original: " + key + "<br/>";
                string[] motToCut = key.ToString().Split(' ');
                Dictionary<string, int> MoviesListMissing = new Dictionary<string, int>();
                Dictionary<string, string> MoviesListMissingCode = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                Dictionary<string, DateTime> MoviesListMissingDate = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();


                //// on va chercher si un des elements du dico n'a pas été récupéré.
                command2.CommandText = "";
                int counter = 0;

                foreach (string word_cutted in motToCut)
                {
                    // on considere que les mots qui ont plus d'une lettre
                    if (word_cutted.Length > 1)
                    {

                        command2.CommandText += "select Code, Titre, Date from Data where Titre LIKE '%" + word_cutted + "%';";
                        counter++;
                        Console.WriteLine("word_cutted : {0} ", word_cutted);
                    }
                }

                command2.Prepare();  // Calling Prepare after having set the Commandtext and parameters.

                //literaltest.Text += "<br/> on rentre dans le try apres word_cutted : ";

                SqlDataReader reader2 = command2.ExecuteReader();


                try
                {


                    int resultCounter = 1;
                    bool resultUnique = false;
                    string bontitre = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                    {
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            while (reader2.Read())
                            {
                                //literaltest.Text += "<br/> si i = 0 ";
                                if (reader2[1].ToString().Length > 0)
                                {
                                    if (!MoviesListMissing.ContainsKey(reader2[1].ToString()))
                                    {
                                        //literaltest.Text += "<br/> i = 0   mot  : " + reader2[0].ToString() + "," + reader2[1].ToString();
                                        MoviesListMissing.Add(reader2[1].ToString(), 0);
                                        MoviesListMissingCode.Add(reader2[1].ToString(), reader2[0].ToString());
                                        bontitre = reader2[1].ToString();
                                        resultCounter++;
                                        if (reader2[2].ToString().Length > 0)
                                        {
                                            DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(reader2[2].ToString());
                                            //literaltest.Text += "<br/> date Conversion orginal:" + reader2[2].ToString() + " new : " + dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                                            MoviesListMissingDate.Add(reader2[1].ToString(), dt);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        else if (!resultUnique)
                        {
                            // on réinitialise le compteur
                            resultCounter = 1;
                            reader2.NextResult();
                            while (reader2.Read())
                            {
                                if (reader2[1].ToString().Length > 0)
                                {
                                    //literaltest.Text += "<br/> i :  " + i + " mot : " + reader2[0].ToString() + "," + reader2[1].ToString();
                                    if (!MoviesListMissing.ContainsKey(reader2[1].ToString()))
                                    {
                                        MoviesListMissing.Add(reader2[1].ToString(), 0);
                                        MoviesListMissingCode.Add(reader2[1].ToString(), reader2[0].ToString());
                                        MoviesListMissingDate.Add(reader2[1].ToString(), Convert.ToDateTime(reader2[2].ToString()));
                                        bontitre = reader2[1].ToString();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        //on incremente le nombre de point.
                                        MoviesListMissing[reader2[1].ToString()] += 1;
                                        bontitre = reader2[1].ToString();
                                    }
                                    resultCounter++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (resultCounter == 2)
                        {
                            // si on a eu qu'un retour lors d'une requete pour un mot alors c'est la bonne
                            resultUnique = true;
                            Console.WriteLine("ResultUnique true");
                            //break;
                        }
                    }
                    bool MoviesListMissingisEmpty = (MoviesListMissing.Count == 0);
                    if (!MoviesListMissingisEmpty)
                    {
                        if (resultUnique == false)
                        {
                            // liste le dictionnaire
                            int keyMax = 0;
                            string trueKey = MoviesListMissing.Keys.First();
                            string falseKey = "";
                            bool unique = true;
                            // on regarde quel titre a le plus de point.
                            foreach (string cle in MoviesListMissing.Keys)
                            {
                                if (MoviesListMissing[cle] > keyMax)
                                {
                                    keyMax = MoviesListMissing[cle];
                                    trueKey = cle;
                                    unique = true;
                                    falseKey = "";
                                }
                                else if (MoviesListMissing[cle] == keyMax)
                                {
                                    unique = false;
                                    falseKey += cle + ", ";
                                }
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine("Le bon titre est : {0} ", trueKey);
                            Console.WriteLine("Le bon titre est unique ? : {0} falsekey: {1}", unique.ToString(), falseKey);
                            // si le nombre max est détenue par un seul titre
                            if (unique)
                            {
                                bontitre = trueKey;
                                // on rajoute le code
                                MList[key.ToString()] = MoviesListMissingCode[trueKey];
                            }
                            else
                            // on regarde la date
                            {

                                string[] CuttedByDate = falseKey.ToString().Split(' ');
                                DateTime bestDate = MoviesListMissingDate[CuttedByDate[0]];
                                bontitre = CuttedByDate[0];
                                foreach (string wordDate in CuttedByDate)
                                {
                                    if ((Math.Abs(today.Subtract(MoviesListMissingDate[CuttedByDate[0]]).Days)) < Math.Abs(today.Subtract(bestDate).Days))
                                    {
                                        bontitre = wordDate;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Le bon titre trouvé de maniere unique : {0} ", bontitre);
                            MList[key.ToString()] = MoviesListMissingCode[bontitre];
                        }
                    }

                    // liste le dictionnaire
                    foreach (string key2 in MList.Keys)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Last version : {0}, {1} ", key2, MList[key2]);
                    }



                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
                    Console.WriteLine("Last version : {0}", e);
                }
                finally
                {
                    // Always call Close when done reading.
                    reader2.Close();

                }

            }

            connection3.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(" Avant var key in keysWithMatchingValues ");             

        }


    }
```

Comment: Please show the stack trace you're getting. I find it hard to believe that it's `Close` that's throwing the exception. I suspect the problem is actually in some of the code you've snipped. It would be best if you could produce a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure what is a stack trace, maybe you are referring to the image I put in the begining ?

Comment: You probably have omitted the actual rows which cause this exception. The only thing causing this would be if you would add/remove something to keysWithMatchingValues collection inside foreach loop.

Comment: Doing a short version of this program would be difficult since the it is pretty complex, but in short what I am doing is changing the value for some keys of MList. 
I don't thinks I am touching keysWithMatchingValues collection, but I posted the complete code if it may help.

Comment: @Exia0890: Yes, that's the stack trace. So which line is 365 in your code?

Comment: Based on the screenshot the error is first thrown on line 365 in your application (it helps a lot to turn on line numbers in Visual Studio). What exactly do you have on that line?

Comment: It is this one `foreach (var key in keysWithMatchingValues)`, and there is only one key in keysWithMatchingValues, so the code is only runing once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this is the problem - you're modifying `MList` while you're iterating through a *lazily evaluated* query based on it:

```
MList[key.ToString()] = MoviesListMissingCode[bontitre];
```

and

```
MList[key.ToString()] = MoviesListMissingCode[trueKey];
```

You're not allowed to do that.

The simplest way to fix this is simply to take a *copy* of the key/value pairs as part of the query. So this:

```
var keysWithMatchingValues = MList.Where(p => Equals(p.Value, "0")).Select(p => p.Key);
```

can become:

```
var keysWithMatchingValues = MList.ToList()
                                  .Where(p => Equals(p.Value, "0"))
                                  .Select(p => p.Key);
```

Although personally I'd rewrite it as:

```
var keysWithMatchingValues = MList.ToList()
                                  .Where(p => p.Value == "0")
                                  .Select(p => p.Key);
```

At this point, you're fine to modify `MList` as you iterate over `keysWithMatchingValues`, because they're separated.

(I'd also break up this mammoth method into smaller ones.)

Comment: Thanks it worked, although I admit I am not sure what was the problem, and why what you did solved it. The Code is indeed pretty big there was so much case to treat that it was not easy.

Comment: @Exia0890: Fundamentally, you were changing the collection you were iterating over, while you were iterating over it. That's prohibited in almost all .NET collections.

Comment: I see, I thought keysWithMatchingValues  was an object completely separated from MList, but it seems it was not the case. Anyway Thanks.

Comment: @Exia0890: I think it would be worth you learning more about how LINQ works, and LINQ to Objects in particular. It's really important to understand how that side of things works.