# Collection was modified error when looping through list and removing items

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have the following:

```
 tempLabID = lstLab;
                    foreach (string labID in lstLab)
                    {
                        if (fr.GetFileRecipients(fsID).Contains(labID))
                        {
                            tempLabID.Remove(labID);
                        }
                    }
```

When I debug and watch lstLab and I get to tempLabID.remove() it changes lstLab to 0 from 1, and then in turn, when it gets back to the foreach I get an error saying the collection has been modified.

I can't understand why it's happening. I am modifying a different collection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963376/system-invalidoperationexception-collection-was-modified-error)

Answer (score 5):

No, you are modifying the same collection. You have two variables pointing to the same collection. Your first line needs to clone the collection for it to work.

You can modify your code so that you don't have that problem:

```
lstLab.RemoveAll( labID => fr.GetFileRecipients(fsID).Contains(labID) );
```

This will remove all those you want to remove, without the need for loops or temp copies.

Answer (score 1):

you can't do that.

change the

`tempLabID = lstlab;`

to

`tempLabID = lstLab.ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

You're not modifying a different collection since both `tempLabID` and `lstLab` are pointing to the same collection.

Try:

```
tempLabID = lstLab.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the same collection because tempLabID = lstLab copy the reference (pointer) to the collection, but it doesn't clone the collection.

You probably want to clone the collection:

```
tempLabID = lstLab.ToArray();
```

Comment: `ToArray` is not going to work, because OP uses `tempLabID.Remove`.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem:

```
tempLabID = lstLab.Where(l => fr.GetFileRecipients(fsID).Contains(l)).ToList();
```

For further explanation read [Jon Skeets answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963376/system-invalidoperationexception-collection-was-modified-error)

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, I usually just loop through the list backwards.  (Not very fancy but it works.)

```
    for (int x = lstLab.Count - 1; x >= 0; x--)
    {
        string labId = lstLab[x];
        if (fr.GetFileRecipients(fsID).Contains(labID))        
           lstLab.RemoveAt(x);        
    }
```